Google Sign In Not working on Debug and Released. Log says | [GoogleAuthUtil] [GoogleAuthUtil] error status:UNKNOWN with method:getTokenWithDetails
It has impacted all the users both Debug and Released modes older downloads are also impacted, I've checked both SHA1 and SHA256 and they are same as they were when it was working perfectly fine. No Firebase Console or Google Cloud console Settings have been disturbed.
Suddenly 1 device worked but others are still not working. All the versions and Devices are impacted.
Checked SHA1 and SHA256 Keys and it seems completely fine.
Using Firebase On flutter.
